# Safari and Vimeo iframe fullscreen issue

Tags: safari, vimeo

I'm facing an issue with Safari (Version 11.0.3), when embedding a video from Vimeo.

I'm using a video as a background for my page. There is a sort of 're-sizing' mode on Safari when you load the page, it first appears on it's original size and then finally fill the space. But on other browsers it's directly on occupying the whole space as background-cover mode.

You can see it on a Codepen here: https://codepen.io/abennington/full/ZONqqv/

```
.vimeo-wrapper iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 56.25vw; /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 9/16*100 = 56.25 */
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 177.77vh; /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 16/9*100 = 177.77 */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

and what I meant in screenshot:
[First screenshot, Video is embedded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd93B.jpg) 
[Second screenshot, Video is finally filling the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrm34.jpg)

Does anyone know how it can be solved?

Comment: Does this happen in a production environment outside of Codepen? Just want to eliminate any variables.

Comment: It does happen in production (online, local)